# Commutation relations for spin operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, commutator

I am trying to prove the following theorem in a QM book that I am studying: $[L_i,x_j]=i\hbar\epsilon_{ijk}x_k$, where $x_1=x$, $x_2=y$ and $x_3=z$. I am starting by working on the example case of $i=1$ and $j=2$, so I want to prove that $[L_1,y]=i\hbar z$. With some manipulation, $[L_1,y]$ comes out to:
$$-i\hbar\left(y\frac{\partial}{\partial z}-z\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)y+i\hbar y\left(y\frac{\partial}{\partial z}-z\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right).$$ However, because $y$ is a constant operator (meaning it's basically just treated as a scalar multiple) while $L_x$ is a linear operator, it seems like I can just pull the factor of $y$ out to get that the desired commutator is
$$-i\hbar y\left(y\frac{\partial}{\partial z}-z\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)+i\hbar y\left(y\frac{\partial}{\partial z}-z\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)=0.$$What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this gets much clearer if you apply the operators to states (i.e. functions as $\psi(x,y,z)$.
You should prove that
$$
[L_x, y] \psi = i\hbar z \psi,
$$
the left hand side can be expanded as
$$
-i\hbar \left(y \partial_z - z \partial_y \right) (y\psi) + i\hbar y \left(y\partial_z - z\partial_y \right)\psi.
$$
Now you see that $\partial_y (y\psi) = \psi + y\partial_y\psi$ is the derivative of a product! so after canceling out some terms you are left with
$$
i\hbar z \psi.
$$

Answer (score 3):

When computing all these commutators, remember there is always a wavefunction, on which the operators act, implied. Example:
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial y} \{ y \,\psi(x,y,z)  \} = \psi(x,y,z) + y \, \frac{\partial }{\partial y} \,\psi(x,y,z) $$

Therefore for mnemonic purposes we write it as
$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial y} y   = 1 + y \, \frac{\partial }{\partial y}  $$